# How do I extract specific rows from a CSV file?

Tags: python, object

I have three `CSV` files:

`doctors.csv`

```
1,John,Smith,Internal Med
2,Jone,Smith,Pediatrics
3,Jone,Carlos,Cardiology
```

`patients.csv`

```
1,Sara,Smith,20,07012345678,B1234
2,Mike,Jones,37,07555551234,L22AB
3,Daivd,Smith,15,07123456789,C1ABC
```

... and `linked.csv`, which I need to populate based on `doctors.csv` and `patients.csv`.

I'm taking two inputs from the user that correspond with the `doctor ID` and `patient ID`, and checking if they are present, and then writing them to the `linked.csv` file.

I'd like the `linked.csv` file to contain for each column:

```
[patientID,patientfirstname,patientsurname,doctorID,doctorfirstname,doctorlastname]
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to read a specific row using the `csv` module and then extract the specific data I need from both files.

Here is the code I have so far:

```py
#asking for input
print('Please select both a Patient ID and Doctor ID to  link together')
patient_index = input('Please enter the patient ID: ')
doctorlink = input('Please select a doctor ID: ')
doctorpresent = False
patientpresent = False

# precence check for both values
with open('patiens.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            if patient_index == row[0]: 
                print('Patient is present')
                patientpresent = True
with open('doctors.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            if patient_index == row[0]: 
                print('Doctor is present')
                doctorpresent = True

if patientpresent == True and doctorpresent == True:
```

Here, I need to add the code necessary for extracting the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used CSV library to read files from both files and combine them into a list.

```
import csv

# asking for input
print('Please select both a Patient ID and Doctor ID to  link together')
patient_index = input('Please enter the patient ID: ')
doctor_index = input('Please select a doctor ID: ')

output = []

# opening the CSV file
with open('patient.csv', 'r') as f:
  # reading the CSV file
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  # iterating the rows
  for row in reader:
    if patient_index == row[0]:
        output.append(row[0])  # appending patientID
        output.append(row[1])  # appending patientfirstname
        output.append(row[2])  # appending patientlastname

# opening the CSV file
with open('doctor.csv', 'r') as f:
  # reading the CSV file
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  # iterating the rows
  for row in reader:
    if doctor_index == row[0]:
        output.append(row[0])  # appending doctorID
        output.append(row[1])  # appending doctorfirstname
        output.append(row[2])  # appending doctorlastname

print(output)
```

**Output**

```
['1', 'Sara', 'Smith', '1', 'John', 'Smith'] 
[patientID,patientfirstname,patientsurname,doctorID,doctorfirstname,doctorlastname]
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a task better suited for a database, but here is a possible solution just using the `csv` module ([`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) here is just my preferred way to handle files):

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path

# Files
patients_csv = Path('patients.csv')
doctors_csv = Path('doctors.csv')
linked_csv = Path('linked.csv')

# Create in memory lists for patients and doctors
with patients_csv.open() as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    patients = [_ for _ in reader]

with doctors_csv.open() as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    doctors = [_ for _ in reader]

print('Please select both a Patient ID and Doctor ID to  link together')
patient_id = input('Please enter the patient ID: ')
doctor_id = input('Please select a doctor ID: ')

# Is there a doctor that matches doctor_id?
doctor = [_ for _ in doctors if _[0] == doctor_id]

# Is there a patient that matches patient_id?
patient = [_ for _ in patients if _[0] == patient_id]

# Do we have a patient and a doctor match?
if patientt and doctor:
    patient = patient[0]
    doctor = doctor[0]
    with linked_csv.open('a') as f:
        print(*patient, *doctor, file=f, sep=',')
```

And here is the result of a test run of the code above, which is in `app.py` here:

```bash
$ ls
app.py  doctors.csv  patients.csv

$ cat doctors.csv 
1,John,Smith,Internal Med
2,Jone,Smith,Pediatrics
3,Jone,Carlos,Cardiology

$ cat patients.csv 
1,Sara,Smith,20,07012345678,B1234
2,Mike,Jones,37,07555551234,L22AB
3,Daivd,Smith,15,07123456789,C1ABC

$ python app.py 
Please select both a Patient ID and Doctor ID to  link together
Please enter the patient ID: 1
Please select a doctor ID: 1

$ cat linked.csv 
1,Sara,Smith,20,07012345678,B1234,1,John,Smith,Internal Med
```

It can also be implemented independent of the `csv` module:

```py
from pathlib import Path

# Files
patients_csv = Path('patients.csv')
doctors_csv = Path('doctors.csv')
linked_csv = Path('linked.csv')

# Create in memory lists for patients and doctors
with patients_csv.open() as f:
    patients = [_.strip().split(',') for _ in f]

with doctors_csv.open() as f:
    doctors = [_.strip().split(',') for _ in f]

print('Please select both a Patient ID and Doctor ID to  link together')
patient_id = input('Please enter the patient ID: ')
doctor_id = input('Please select a doctor ID: ')

# Is there a doctor that matches doctor_id?
doctor = [_ for _ in doctors if _[0] == doctor_id]

# Is there a patient that matches patient_id?
patient = [_ for _ in patients if _[0] == patient_id]

# Do we have a patient and a doctor match?
if patientt and doctor:
    patient = patient[0]
    doctor = doctor[0]
    with linked_csv.open('a') as f:
        print(*patient, *doctor, file=f, sep=',')
```

Both examples are just starting points, which you can construct and improve above them.

Comment: Yeah it would be but its a Uni assignment and its one function in another larger program.

Comment: In that case, you must update your question and post all the details. The answer I posted addresses only the specific question from your post.